# How to save the discord user that used the slash command corresponding to the button in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make an application slash command that sends the application to a mod channel, where the mods can either accept or deny the application.

But currently if 2 users use the /apply2 command, the button that is send to the carrier-app-log channel will both give roles to the user that used the command second (because the global variable id is set to the new id)

```py
@client.tree.command(name="apply2", description="Apply for carrier")
@app_commands.describe(player_name="Player Name", profile="Profile Name", floor="Floor", proof="Proof")
async def apply2(interaction: discord.Interaction, player_name: str, profile: str, floor: int, proof: discord.Attachment):
  global id
  global role



  get_player_profile(player_name, "dungeons", profile)
  if check_reqs_dungeon(floor):
    global role
    await interaction.response.send_message("Submitted Succesfully", ephemeral=True)
    channel = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.channels, name="carrier-app-log")
    embed=discord.Embed(title=player_name.capitalize(), url=f"https://sky.shiiyu.moe/stats/{player_name}/{profile}", description=f"{interaction.user.mention} applied for floor {floor} carrier on account {player_name.capitalize()}", color=368)
    id=interaction.user
    role=floorRoles[floor-1]
    print(role)
    embed.set_image(url=proof.proxy_url)

  
    await channel.send(embed=embed, view=ApplyButtons())
  else:
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"You do not meet the minimum requirements for floor {floor}, the minimum requirement is {floorReqs[floor-1]}", ephemeral=True)
  



class ApplyButtons(discord.ui.View):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(timeout=None)

  @discord.ui.button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="accept")
  async def accept(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    global role
    global id
    user = id
    print(user)
    print(role)
    if type(role) is int:
      role=interaction.guild.get_role(role)
      print(role)
      print("Converted")
    if role not in user.roles:
      print("Not in user roles")
      await user.add_roles(role)
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"{role.mention} role given to {user.mention}", ephemeral=False)
    else:
      print("In user roles")
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"Applicant already have {role.mention} role", ephemeral=False)
```

I tried to set the the custom_id of the button to be the original global id, and was hoping I can access the custom_id of the button for the username everytime the button is pressed. `@discord.ui.button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id=id)`
`user = self.custom_id`

but an attribute error is returned saying
"AttributeError: 'ApplyButtons' object has no attribute 'custom_id'"

Thanks ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not use global variables.** For Discord bots in particular, where commands are ran often by different users with different information, using global variables is bad practice.

The way to use a variable from a command function to a view class, is by taking it as an argument when initialising the class. In other words, make `__init__` take an argument.

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user): #  <-
        super().__init__()
        self.user = user #  Storing it as an attribute in the class

    @discord.ui.button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="accept")
    async def accept(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        user = self.user #  Getting the user argument


@client.tree.command(name="command")
async def command_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
     await interaction.response.send_message(...,
                                             view=MyView(interaction.user)) #  Parsing the argument
```

Another thing to note: try not to use built-in function names as a variable name.

`id` is a function, so you shouldn't be using it as a variable because it overwrites its use. This is especially important since in your code, `id` is a global variable. Otherwise, it would only overwrite the `id` function locally (in the function it is defined in).

`@discord.ui.button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id=id) user = self.custom_id` would also not work.

```
var = None

class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id=var)
    async def accept(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        var = self.custom_id
```

`self` refers to the class. Methods in a class, like the button callback, take in an argument we conventional name `self`. This is the class object.

If you want to access the custom_id, you instead want to take it from the button itself, not the class.

```
    @discord.ui.button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="accept")
    async def accept(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        custom_id = button.custom_id
```